Laravel JWTException handling
Why the following code raises error "Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException: Token could not be parsed from the request "  Eventhougn its handled with try and catch?
    try{
        $user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();
        return $next($request);
    }
    catch(Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException $e)
    {
        return response(['message'=>"First login to the system"], 503);
    }


is this PHP file this code in declared with a namespace at the top?
